# mIRC stop spam of bot - Twitch

Tags: irc, mirc, twitch

Here's my code;

```
on *:text:!points:#:{ 
  msg # $nick has $readini(Points.ini,$+(#,.,$nick),Points) total points. 
}
```

Thats ok but if 5 people do !points in a row, it spams the chat. How do I make it update every 10 seconds and then display a message with the points of the people who have asked in that ten seconds but all in one message?

Comment: A better solution will be serve only 3 people in 5 seconds, Is that good for you ?

Comment: Yeah! Could you post that for me? I can't code it at all :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that will only take 3 requests in 5 seconds.

```
on *:text:!points:#: {
    inc -u5 %flood. [ $+ [ # ] $+ ]
    if (%flood. [ $+ [ # ] ] > 3) {
        return
    }
    msg # $nick has $readini(Points.ini,$+(#,.,$nick),Points) total points. 
}
```

Comment: @user3764992, Sure no problem, If you liked it, consider up voting the answer + Accept Answer.

Comment: I will. I just want to see a few more answers!

Comment: BTW you can only accept an answer after 15 min, and with 1 rep, he can't vote up.